# Getting most occured string value using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, count

I have a list of strings which I group by their occurrence in the list like following (where key is the list of those strings):

```
  mostCommonKeywords = key.GroupBy(v => v)
                            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) // here I get the count number
                            .Select(g => g.Key)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

The thing I want to do now is when they are sorted out, I wanna get their count, since LINQ can clearly distinguish their number and sort them out... How can I get the count occurrence of each string in the list now ???

Edit:

Let's say I have count values that look like this:

```
124
68
55
48
32
19
13
10
```

I cannot simply Add 1 of this value into a variable called "Count" as @octavioccl suggested.  I clearly have to store them into some kind of list or something...

Comment: You don't need the `Distinct` since the result of `GroupBy` will be a set of unique keys.  Also to have the count just include it in the `Select`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `Select` and projecting in an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

```
 var result=key.GroupBy(v => v)
               .Select(g => new {g.Key, Count=g.Count()})
               .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count) 
            // .Distinct()// Don't need this call
               .ToList();
```

### Update

You can also project your query using a DTO:

```
public class CustomDTO
{
  public string Key{get;set;} // Change the type in case you need to
  public int Count{get;set;}
}
```

So, your query would be:

```
 var result=key.GroupBy(v => v)
               .Select(g => new CustomDTO{Key=g.Key, Count=g.Count()})
               .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count) 
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Imagine I have 500 of these... I'm gonna need more than just a simple variable to store 1 value.. We are talking about 500 different values, I'll need to store them into a list or something all at once... Do you understand what I'm trying to say? :)

Comment: Not really :(, could you update your question with an example

Comment: @User987 your edit is exactly what this answer does. Check the .Key variable

Comment: Oh goodness it seems ur right... This is it... By the way , what type will the result be?? It's clearly not just a generic list?

Comment: Excellent excellent, this is even better than I've imagined. Thanks mate!! :) Accepted ur answer ! :D

Comment: @User987 It's an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Comment: Although if you're selecting a CustomDTO it could be a CustomDTO type.

Answer (score -1):

```
from a in keys
group a by a.key into g
select new { a.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: You mean `group a by a into g`  Also why delete an answer and just create another one that's basically the same?

Comment: The important thing here isn't to use query syntax instead of method syntax, but the fact that you include the `Count` in the select.  But currently your group by is wrong because `a` is a `string` and does not have a `key` member.